# Registration system in lumen

Tags: authentication, registration, lumen

I want to setup a user registration system in my app, but for this I am using Lumen as a backend. However, I am unsure, how to proceed with it.

I have got a multiple options available for authentication like jwt, or oauth, but I am unsure how to get users registered in first place.